# Sphinx templating

Tags: python, templates, python-sphinx

I am using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org). I want to template it. So after reading the docs, what I am trying is, in my conf.py,

I put a line like,

```
templates_path = ['_templates']
```

and I created a file

```
_templates/page.html
```

But this does not override the default template provided by sphinx. What more should I do, and where does this template need to go?

---

**EDIT:**

Directory structure from the comments:

```
conf.py
abc.txt
def.txt
makefile
_templates\
   page.html
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be sure you are using the theme name as an explicit directory in your template.  e.g.:

`{% extends "basic/layout.html" %}`

see: [HTML Theming Support](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html#templating)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#working-with-the-builtin-templates
says that the template it's looking for is `layout.html`.

Perhaps you should use that name.

Comment: That template would be the one used to do layout, i believe. That would be needed, If say I wanted to change the position of sidebar. But I want to add something to the body. 

There is a template called page.html in sphinx/themes/basic/, which I want to override.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Perhaps you need to force a rebuild for all files with the command `sphinx-build -a`? Sphinx only compiles HTML files that it detects as having changed. Another option is to just touch all your source files with `touch *.rst`.